# How can I make backticks execute on shell script that backgrounds job

Tags: shell

This command does not terminate

```bash
echo `bash -c 'tail -f /dev/null & echo hello world'`
```

despite the fact that

```bash
bash -c 'tail -f /dev/null & echo hello world'
```

correctly returns "hello world"

I am trying to background a command inside a bash script that is evaluated inside backticks. I actually need to run eval and not echo, for for this example I'm using echo. The script in question emulates an ssh-agent which outputs typically a number of export statements. However, inside the script I need to background a job.

I have tried to use `disown`, `nohup` or `$()` instead of backticks. It seems that the backticks always wait for the termination of all child processes. Is there a way to circumvent this? I particularly would be interested in receiving the PID of the backgrounded command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
echo `shell code`
```

Which is the deprecated form of:

```
echo $(shell code)
```

`shell code` is evaluated in a subshell and its *whole* output, stripped of the trailing newline characters and, since you forgot to quote it, subject to split+glob is passed as argument to `echo`.

To do that, the shell makes the stdout of that subshell a pipe, and at the other end of the pipe, the shell reads the output until end-of-file, that is, until all processes that have their stdout (or any other fd) open on that pipe either close those fds or terminate.

In:

```
echo "$(sleep 10 & echo done)"
```

Even though `sleep 10` is run asynchronously and its termination is not waited for by the subshell, the process running `sleep` still has its stdout (fd 1) open on the pipe and it will remain so until it exits, so the shell will have to wait until `sleep` terminates to know that there's no more output to be read.

If you change it to:

```
echo "$(sleep 10 > /dev/null & echo done)"
```

You'll see it returns instantly while `sleep` carries on running in background as `sleep` in that case doesn't have any fd open onto the pipe.

Comment: I can't undestand why  
'echo `bash -c 'tail -f /dev/null & echo hello world'`' does not terminate as TO claims

Comment: @gapsf, same thing, `tail` has its stdout on the pipe.

Comment: @ Stéphane Chazelas     So it prints 'hellow world' and  'tail -f /dev/null' runs forever? Or commands splited and just tail runs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer the funny thing is that I tried this and my non-reduced version still has the problem. Btw I would disagree with deprecation (backticks are just the old posix way which work fine if you won't nest.)

Comment: @till, they are nestable alright, they're just very painful to use properly (with quotes), causes hard to spot/debug problems with backslash inside and there are portability issues as well.

Comment: I actually tried to redirect stdout but actually messed up the order of >/dev/null 2>&1 :) this is actually why I needed it: https://gist.github.com/riedel/808529121892efdba444ac82df4c5f15 . Works now with eval just like ssh-agent

Answer (score 1):

> I particularly would be interested in receiving the PID of the backgrounded command.

My guess you want pid of `tail`, not a `bash`.

You don't have to use `bash -c` just

`tail -f /dev/null & echo $!`